# V Snare T Snare Model

Tags: c, bioinformatics

In the beginning, everything is defined to be of value 10, but I have to change them to suit them for different possible values, hence those are changing. I'm a (Im)mature C coder, hence there might be trivial mistakes. I would like to get feedback on how to improve it.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


#define M  10          
#define MAX 1023      
#define N 10         
#define snareLength 10

_Bool nondet_bool();
unsigned int nondet_uint();

typedef unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[M] bitvector; 
typedef unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[snareLength] snareVector; 

//  Constrine the value between 0 and 1
unsigned int  nondet (){  
   unsigned int num = nondet_uint();
   __CPROVER_assume( num>= 0 && num  <= 1);
   return num;
 };

unsigned int zeroTon(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int result = nondet_uint();
    __CPROVER_assume(result >=0 && result <=n);
    return result ;
 };

 //  Define the Structure of the Container Going to be used -----------------------------------------
struct EdgeBag
 {
  int ith;
  int jth;
  unsigned int count;
  bitvector edgeWeight;
  snareVector  vSnare;
  snareVector tSnare;
  snareVector combinedMask;  
};


//  Setweight function allow only subset to out!
bitvector setWeight( bitvector node) {
     bitvector edge;
     edge = 0b0;
     for(unsigned int k=0; k<M; k++){
         if ((node & (0b1 << k)) == (0b1 << k)) {
                edge =  (edge |  (nondet() << k));
           } 
     }
     return edge;
}


void main()
{    
unsigned int pos , i, j, k, l, w, x, y , iVal, jVal;
unsigned int edgePos, bagNo = 0, colorNode = 0 , minColor, cPos = 0;
unsigned int len = 0, ticks, valj, vali ;
_Bool Ck, Cf, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5; 

bitvector compartment1 , compartment2, compartment3 , compartment4 , compartment5 ;
bitvector compartment6 , compartment7 , compartment8 ,compartment9 , compartment10;

bitvector nodes[N] = {compartment1, compartment2, compartment3, compartment4, compartment5, compartment6, compartment7,  compartment8, compartment9, compartment10};

bitvector  fareTotal, inTotal, outTotal ;
snareVector total, cond2Total, cond2fareTotal, centTotal, placeHolder, v, t, f;

//  FriendMatrix is v * t-snare matrix where v snares are rows and T snares are columns
snareVector friendMatrix[snareLength];     
//  OnOffMatrix is the N * t-snare matrix where N:nodes are rows and T snares are column  
snareVector onOffMatrix[N], stCorres, mask , ew ;

// Input the graph *******************************************
unsigned int graph[N][N] =  { {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0},
              {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2},
              {1,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
              {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0},
              {0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0},
              {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  0},
              {0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0},
              {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0},
              {0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0},
              {2,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0}};


 //  Calculate the total required length that is required for our container
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if(graph[i][j] == 1) {
            len = len + 1;
        }
        else if(graph[i][j] == 2) {
              len =  len + 2;
        }
      } 
}

 //  Define the Container as Basis of our work  --------------------------
 struct EdgeBag edgeBag[len];

//  Fill the Container values with i, j, edgeWeigth, vsnare, tsnare Values.
edgePos = 0;
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
        if ((graph[i][j] == 1) || (graph[i][j] == 2)) {
              edgeBag[edgePos].ith = i;
              edgeBag[edgePos].jth = j;
              edgeBag[edgePos].edgeWeight  = setWeight(nodes[i]);
              ew = edgeBag[edgePos].edgeWeight;
              edgeBag[edgePos].vSnare = setWeight(ew);
              edgeBag[edgePos].tSnare  = setWeight(ew) ;
              edgePos = edgePos + 1;
        }

        if (graph[i][j] == 2) {
              edgeBag[edgePos].ith = i;
              edgeBag[edgePos].jth = j;
              edgeBag[edgePos].edgeWeight = setWeight(nodes[i]);
              ew = edgeBag[edgePos].edgeWeight;
              edgeBag[edgePos].vSnare = setWeight(ew);
              edgeBag[edgePos].tSnare  = setWeight(ew) ;
              edgePos = edgePos + 1;
        }
     }
}

//  Edgeweight is not allowed to be zero : build C0 to represent that :
C0 = 1; 
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
     C0 = C0 && (edgeBag[j].edgeWeight != 0);
 }

 // Assume No two edgeweight are same in the array edgeBag[len] :
 for  (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for  (j = 0; (j != i) && (j < len) ; j++) {
       __CPROVER_assume(edgeBag[i].edgeWeight != edgeBag[j].edgeWeight);
    }

 }

 //  STEADY STATE CONDITION BEGINS --------------------------------------- 
//  The inflow of type of molecule is same as outflow of type of the molecule.
//  Different type of molecules coming in is same as differnt type of molecules going out.
C1 = 1;
 for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
     iVal = i;
     outTotal = 0b0;
     inTotal  = 0b0;

     for(j = 0; j < len; j++) {
             if (edgeBag[j].ith == iVal) {
                         outTotal = (outTotal | edgeBag[j].edgeWeight);
             }

             if (edgeBag[j].jth  == iVal) {
                         inTotal = (inTotal | edgeBag[j].edgeWeight);
             }
     }

     C1 = C1 && (inTotal == outTotal);

 }


 //  STEADY STATE CONDITION ENDS -----------------------------------------

 for  (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       __CPROVER_assume (edgeBag[i].edgeWeight == (edgeBag[i].vSnare | edgeBag[i].tSnare)); 

 }

 //  Define FRIEND Matrix : 
 for  (i = 0; i < snareLength; i++) {
     friendMatrix[i] = zeroTon(MAX); 
 }

 // THE BASIC CONSTRAINTS BEGINS --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 /*=================================================================
  * Steps :

* 1. Check if the ith Vsnare is present on current Edge ?
*
* 2. Check if its corresponding frd t-snares (t required for fusion), 
*    based on FriendMatrix are all absent on the current edge.
* 
* 3. Then check if the t-snare required for fusion are all present on 
*    target edge and all are in On Conditions based on OnOffMatrix.
*
* 4. Check if t snares required for fusion are not all present on the 
*    source node of the current edge or they are off.
*    
*    **** I'm implimenting it as just checking OnOffMatrix and make 
*    ***  sure all are not onn to avoid the case that it might be 
*    **   on even if its not present.

   ======================================*/
 C2 = 1; C3 = 1;
 for  (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    centTotal = 0b0;
    total = 0b0;
    ticks = 0;
    Ck = 0;   
    //  Check if jth vSnare is present then check if all its t-snare frds are present on the edge. 
    //  If yes don't consider him as a cnadidate to check the fusion that happens btw current nodes.
    //  POINT I MISSED : Make sure that t snares are onn, on target node. 
    for  (j = 0; j < snareLength; j++) {
       v = edgeBag[i].vSnare;
       t = edgeBag[i].tSnare;
       f = friendMatrix[j];
       valj = edgeBag[i].jth;
       vali = edgeBag[i].ith;

       if( (v & (1 << j)) && ((t & f) != f) ){
 //         edgeBag[i].zebraMask[ticks] = f;  
          centTotal = centTotal | f;
          ticks = ticks + 1;

          //  Target Edge Should have all required t snares present and Onn in Order to Make fusion Possible.       
          if ( ((nodes[valj]  & onOffMatrix[valj] ) == f )) {
             Ck = Ck || 1 ;                                  
          }
       }
     }

     edgeBag[i].combinedMask = centTotal;
     edgeBag[i].count = ticks;

     if(Ck == 1) {
         C2 = C2 && 1;
     }
     else {
         C2 = C2 && 0;
     }

     mask = edgeBag[i].combinedMask;

     // The combined mask pattern is absent in the all other nodes or 
     // the onOffMatrix cause all the tsnares that are pattern to be absent.
     for (k = 0; (k < N) ; k++){
             //  You can clean It too
        if (k != edgeBag[i].jth){
             if( (( mask & nodes[k]) == 0) || ((mask & onOffMatrix[k]) == 0) ){
                 C3 = C3 && 1;
              }
             else {
                C3 = C3 && 0;
              }
        }
      }
    }

 __CPROVER_assert(!( C0 && C1 && C2 && C3 ), "Graph that satisfy friendZoned model exists");  

}
```

Comment: We improve existing code, not add features on top of it. But you say _everything is defined to be of value 10, but I have to change them to suit them for different possible values, hence those are changing._ Have you already done that?

Comment: the posted code causes the output to produce 52 errors and warnings.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) .  For starters, we are not going to guess as to which header files you are including.  So edit the code to include the #include statements.  And if any of those header files are non-standard, then post their contents also.   For a simple example of the errors, all valid declarations of `main()` have return type of `int`

Comment: The int thing .. yeah got that.  Yeah conversion warnings i have not looked them.. I'll surely now..  There is no extra header file.

Comment: @Caridorc I do not want added feature. Just need improvement suggestions. Like user3629249 provided if you do provide few more of these will  help me  to learn the basic things you have to put in order to code like a pro.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's hard to make too many recommendations because there's a lot of missing code that we don't know anything about. For example, there is no definition for anything that starts with `__CPROVER__` or `nondet_`, `setWeight()`, etc.  Here are a few general suggestions.

It looks like the array `graph` is static input data.  It's best to place data like this outside a function.  Variables declared inside a function are allocated on the stack, and a program has a limited amount of stack memory.  Variables allocated at the file scope are allocated on the heap, where much more memory is available.  Your current approach may work for you at the moment, but it's not going to scale well as `N` grows.

You have the following code at the top of your `main` function:

```
bitvector compartment1 , compartment2, compartment3 , compartment4 , compartment5 ;
bitvector compartment6 , compartment7 , compartment8 ,compartment9 , compartment10;

bitvector nodes[N] = {compartment1, compartment2, compartment3, compartment4, compartment5, compartment6, compartment7,  compartment8, compartment9, compartment10};
```

You declare ten individual bitvectors, then declare an array of ten bitvectors and copy the uninitialized data from the individual bitvectors into it.  You never refer to the individual bitvectors in your code, so they seem to be superfluous.  The initialization is simply copying one set of uninitialized garbage bits on top of another, so it seems superfluous as well.  You can simplify all of this down to just `bitvector nodes[N];`.

You do quite a lot of work inside your 'main' function and allocate a large number of variables.  This is generally a sign that your code can (and should) be broken up into smaller functions that each perform a single, well-defined task.  For example, the 'for' loop inside the "STEADY STATE CONDITION" comments appears to be a self-contained process that takes `edgeBag` as an input and calculates a value for `C1`.  The other variables referenced there do not appear to be accessed anywhere else.  This can be turned into a sub-function.  This makes your code easier to read and debug, and can help reduce memory consumption.

In your function `setWeight`, you use the following test:

```
if ((node & (0b1 << k)) == (0b1 << k))
```

Since you are only masking off a single bit, you don't have to test for equality to the original bitmask (it's not *wrong*, it's just more complex than it needs to be).  Simply using "`if (node & (1 << k))`" should be sufficient.

Instead of using `_Bool` (which isn't defined anywhere so I'm assuming it's a homemade type), use the `bool` type from stdbool.h and the associated constants `true` and `false`.  This should help you clean up your current use of boolean variables, which contains a lot of meaningless code.  For instance, code like `Ck = Ck || 1` is the same thing as `Ck = true`, and code like `C2 = C2 && 1` doesn't actually do anything.

Look for opportunities to exit loops early.  For example, in your "STEADY STATE CONDITION" loop, `C1` starts as 1.  Once it gets set to 0, there's no way for it to get set back to 1 again.  That means that you can stop as soon as `C1` hits zero and avoid wasting time processing more array elements.  Change your loop's terminal condition to `(i < N) && (C1 == 1)`.  This becomes more and more important as your array sizes grow.

Comment: Yup hahahahhah.. "Homemade Type" was awesome. Thanks for recommendation specially regarding the memory usage and how i decrease it. Very helpful. Will take care in each time i write code. i generally use if (node & (0b1 << k)  but somehow i pasted this. Yes you are damn right on that also. Thanks for loop condition suggestions too.

Comment: The thing is i'm using CBMC rather than just C. Its a bounded model checker whose front end is C, so the homeMade types are CBMC types. Yes i'll surely try to get out of the loop , i haven't gave much thought because i was more cocerned about unwindings that CBMC does as it will do unwinding whether you specify it or not.